# Branch of chemistry that deals with reactions between chemicals

Tags: terminology

There are branches of chemistry like physical chemistry that hardly involve chemical reactions. Whereas, inorganic and organic chemistries pretty much definitely have a lot of chemical reactions involved.

Is there a collective name for organic and inorganic chemistries? Is there a single word for the branch of chemistry that deals with the possible products given some reactants and reaction conditions?

Comment: I think your premise is too broad. Perhaps you mean to distinguish between chemists whose work primarily involves **synthesis** and those who primarily deal with other aspects of chemistry?

Comment: @EdV I do not wish to distinguish chemists. It was a question about classifying topics.

Comment: Yep, as I said.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a collective name for organic and inorganic chemistries? Is
> there a single word for the branch of chemistry that deals with the
> possible products given some reactants and reaction conditions?

As a collective term, *synthetic chemistry* refers to a branch of chemistry that deals with chemical reactions that produce new molecules. Please keep in mind that today these chemical branches are hard to distinguish. A synthetic chemist must know a lot of practical spectroscopy (traditional physical chemistry/analytical chemistry) in order to study his /her reactions. Also physical chemists study a lot of chemical reactions.